# Issue when trying to uninstall a gem not present in my gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm a newbie in ruby on rails. I'm trying to deploy to heroku, but when I do

```
git push heroku master
```

I'm experiencing an issue as it states

```
You have added to the Gemfile:
* kmts (~> 2.0.0)
Failed to install gems via Bundler.
```

But I don't see the gem in my gemfile nor in my gemfile.lock. I have tried to uninstall it with

```
gem uninstall kmts
```

but nothing happens.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.1.0.rc2'
gem 'intercom-rails', '~> 0.2.21'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :doc do
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Comment: please include your gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `bundle install` before deploy to heroku, and every time you modify `Gemfile`. Don't forget to `git commit` these changes.

Comment: done, and that's when I see You have added to the Gemfile:
* kmts (~> 2.0.0)
Failed to install gems via Bundler.

Comment: have you add and commit the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to the commit before deploy?